# iOS8 Add Button not showing up in Navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to add the "+" button on the right side of my Navigation Controller. I have added a title to the controller and it works great, however the + button does not show up at all.

```
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
//the buttons
self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"test";
_titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont
                            fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:30], NSFontAttributeName,
                             [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:self.titleTextAttributes];
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addAction:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

any ideas as to why this is occurring? I've tested multiple different things, but have no clue why the button is not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your earlier code speaks of `self.navigationBar` shows what the problem must be. It is only *the top view controller of a UINavigationController* whose `navigationItem` is shown in the navigation bar. So, if you merely have a "loose" navigation bar, or if you *are* a UINavigationController, your `navigationItem` is not shown in the navigation bar. That is why setting `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` is having no visible effect.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm just confused on the difference between the Navigation Controller and Navigation Item. In this code, I am a Navigation Controller, however, a Navigation Item is displayed in my storyboard. How would I fix my code to show the Navigation Item ON the Navigation Controller (if thats the correct terminology)

Comment: I don't quite know what you need to know, or what your view controller hierarchy is, so let me throw too much info at you. :) Here's the discussion in my book of navigation controllers and how they work: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_navigation_controllers And here is the discussion of "loose" navigation bars: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_uinavigationbar

Comment: I just wanted to let you know to fix the problem, I moved the code for the plus button into the View Controller instead of the navigation controller, which fixed the problem. Thanks for your help once again!

Comment: Perfect! Just what I advised in my answer. Well done.